# Travis-CI: An image does not exist locally with the tag

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I know there are plenty of posts in Stackoverflow concerning this or similar topic. However none of the apparently solves my problem. I try to build and push a docker image with Travis-ci. The tagging actually works fine

```
$ docker build -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/$IMAGETAG ./linux/jenkins/
...
Successfully tagged papanito/jenkins:latest
```

However, pushing does not work as it complains of missing local tag

```
...
$ export IMAGETAG=jenkins:latest
$ docker login -u="$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p="$DOCKER_PASSWORD"
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
The command "docker login -u="$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p="$DOCKER_PASSWORD"" exited with 0.
$ docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/$IMAGETAG
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/papanito/jenkins]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: papanito/jenkins
...
```

Interestingly is the last message which does not contain the version info :latest. Whats wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was actually that I split the "build" and the "deploy" of the docker image in 2 different stages. Therefore the second stage didn't knew about the image. If I place all in one stage, the image is uploaded successfully.